# Bad Request error with File Upload Spring MVC 4

Tags: java, jquery, spring, spring-mvc, file-upload

I've the following scenario where getting bad request on form submit. I am using Spring MVC 4 and submitting the form using jquery ajaxSubmit method.

I have a form with multiple file upload. When I submit the form and if file(s) have been selected, it works perfectly. But if I don't select any file, it throws bad request (400) error and not calling the controller method.

For example:

```
public class TestPOJO {
       List<MultipartFile> listArray;   
}

// Controller
public class MyController extends .. {


    public ResponseBody fileUplaod(@Model testpojo) {
            //logic to save it to database
    } 

}
```

Not following the exact syntax, but I know programmers can understand from this.

I have debugged the issue and found that it passes List of string instead of List of multipart file when file is not selected. How to avoid this  ? Any pointers?

Comment: could you add your form ?

Comment: Do you have any validation constraints in your code? Please add the complete code (which concerns file uploading) for both the classes.

Comment: got spring security with csrf?  Please post your actual code